# AppStore: is it possible to distribute separate builds for x86_64 and arm64

Tags: macos, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I would like to avoid distributing a universal binary because it adds hundreds of megabytes extra to the total bundle size. (it's PyTorch dylibs)
I already figured out how to build them separately in XCode, but I'm new to AppStore-Connect, and I'm wondering if it's allowed in AppStore to distribute different builds depending on user's architecture. So far it seems TestFlight makes only separate builds and won't allow a single link to download both architectures. Ideally, I'd like AppStore to just pick the correct architecture when user downloads the app.

So, is it possible to keep two builds for different architectures and have it as a single app in AppStore?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I get downvoted because people think the question is too obvious, but, still, I will post what I found out – that Apple manages my concerns automatically and universal binary is not distributed entirely to end devices. Only required parts are installed. This is the process called App Thining.

Comment: +1 your question is very reasonable. AFAIK it is not possible to upload separate arm64 and x64 builds. You can only upload one single *.app bundle which should include both architectures.